# Transform a specific secret 6 digit number into another 6 digit number

Tags: javascript, cryptography

Is there a way to have a specific 6 digit number to transform into another 6 digit number?

It's meant to be used into a User Interface where the user must know a secret number and it will result into another number.

For instance, the number to obtain is 123456 and the number the user should input is 111111.

So if the user inputs 111111, he will see 123456 which is the right number.

If the user input 222222, he will see something else than 123456 which won't be the right number.

The goal is to avoid telling the user weither he knows the right or wrong secret number to begin with. He could try every combination but won't know 111111 was the right one.

Comment: You should look into format-preserving encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you might take something like a password field that completely hides the input. This way neither your user nor any spectators can guess the right input.

Comment: I guess the user can "guess" what he typed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it.

Plain simple...

I just need to have an encryption that add 0 to the first digit, 1 to the second one, etc.

1111111 will become 123456 (right number), 222222 will become 234567 (useless number).

And nobody can figure the key is 111111.